# How do I place a coordinate midway between two other coordinates using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm struggling to draw a diagram in tikz. I'm trying to do a simple illustration of a parallelogram inside an arbitrary quadrilateral.

I have the following code to place S halfway between O, and P.

Is there a way to do this? Ideally I would get a named coordinate that I can use for further drawing in the end

```tex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, calc,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
%declare points OPQR at random locations
\coordinate[label=right:\textcolor{blue}{$O$}] (O) at ($(0,0) + 3*(rand, rand)$);
\coordinate[label=left:\textcolor{blue}{$P$}] (P) at ($(0,0) + -2*(rand, rand)$);

% I thought something like this would work, but it doesnt
%\coordinate[label=left:\textcolor{orange}{$S$}] (S) at ($0.5* ((O) - (P))$);

\draw[->, name path=A]  (O) -- (P);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I also tried:

```
(O) -- coordinate[midway](S) (P);
```

but when I tried to draw a line from S to another point I got an error that pgf didn't know any shapes by the name `S`.

Comment: With `calc`: `($(P)! 0.5!(Q)$)` is midway between P and Q.

Comment: Have you put a `\path` in front of your last line of code? (btw: this is why we discourage using snippets of code, always use complete, compilable pieces of code.)

Comment: Finally: the midpoint between P and Q is 0.5*(P+Q), not 0.5*(P-Q)... ;-)

Comment: thanks, I have no idea what I'm doing with tikz, i thought it wouldn't be so hard to whip up a simple illustration, oh how wrong I was :P

Comment: I did strip out most of the fat, but there are no `\path`'s left out (although i am intending to draw a line from each midpoint to each other midpoint now I have those worked out :P

Comment: So your last code line did not work - in TikZ you ha e go use a path command (be it `\path`,  `\draw`,  etc...) always. That line was simply text which is ignored by TikZ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\coordinate (S) at ($(O)!0.5!(P)$);` should solve your problem.

Comment: indeed it does, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear, what is the problem. With knowing of the coordinate `S` you draw a rectangle. It can be simply defined as follows:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                calc,
                intersections, 
                through}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
% declare points OPQR at random locations
\coordinate[label=right:\textcolor{blue}{$O$}] (O) at ($(0,0) + 3*(rand, rand)$);
\coordinate[label=left: \textcolor{blue}{$P$}] (P) at ($(0,0) + -2*(rand, rand)$);

\draw[->, name path=A]  (O) -- coordinate[label=left:\textcolor{orange}{$S$}] (S) (P);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
After while (one and half long) without, I see, that looking for something like this:

[image]

Without of use of any Ti*k*Z library a MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[text=blue]
% declare points OPQR at random locations
\coordinate[label=left:$O$]   (O) at (+3*rand,+rand);
\coordinate[label=right:$P$]  (P) at (-3*rand,-rand);
% path + new coordinate on midle of path
\draw[->]  (O) -- coordinate[label=$S$] (S) (P);
\draw[->,red]   (S) -- ++ (1,-1) node[right] {$S'$}; % as example of use S coordinate
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```